# Dancing pairs question, how many ways you can have 5 dancing pairs from 6 boys and 7 girls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways you can have 5 dancing pairs from 6 boys and 7 girls? Assuming  classical dancing pairs (1 boy dancing with 1 girl)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 7!/2! * 6!/1!, I have solved this way, wanted to check if it's correct or not

Comment: No, that is not correct as it incorrectly applies significance to the order in which the pairs appear on the floor.  However, as dancing couples generally will be moving this way and that, we don't care what order the couples are in, we are only interested in who is on the floor and who they are partnered with.

Comment: @JMoravitz, so if the order does not matter, it is a combination, right? And we should calculate ( 7!/5!*2! ) * ( 6!/5!*1! ) * 5! ?

Comment: @AnnieAlan  Your answer $\binom{7}{5}\binom{6}{5}5!$ is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Why do we multiply the two combinations by 5! ? Sorry for bringing back such an old topic.

Comment: @DanielHalachev because otherwise all you did was decide on the ten people on the dance floor (*which boys there are, which girls there are*).  You had not decided yet how to pair them up... which boy dances with which girl and which girl dances with which boy.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick which five boys are participating in the dance.

From those boys selected, one will be the youngest.  Pick which girl dances with the youngest selected boy.

Pick which girl dances with the second youngest selected boy.

Continue in this fashion until all selected boys have a designated dancing partner.

This yields a total of $\binom{6}{5}\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$